# Android map<string, string> to List<Map<String, String>> loops takes on current values only

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, hashmap

Hey all I am trying to add to a list of `map<String, String>` using the code below:

```
@NonNull
public static List<Map<String, String>> mysqlSelect(@NonNull String select, String where) {
    Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<String,String>();
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int selectCnt = select.replaceAll("[^,]","").length();
    final boolean[] b = {true};

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
                String sql = "SELECT fb_firstname, fb_lastname, fb_id FROM fbuser";
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    info.put("name", resultSet.getString("fb_firstname"));
                    info.put("address", resultSet.getString("fb_lastname"));
                    info.put("phone_number", resultSet.getString("fb_id"));

                    list.add(info);
                }

                b[0] = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("InfoAsyncTask", "Error reading school information", e);
                b[0] = false;
            }
        }
    }).start();

    while (b[0]) { }

    return list; //result.get("name")
}
```

As it loops in the `while () {..` part it populates the list with the needed 3 string values. However, as it does loop over and over again it seems to populate all the previous values to what was last read instead of having new data each time?

Example:

1st loop:

```
name: bob barker
address: something
phone-number = 4235421212
```

2nd loop:

```
name: steve jobs
address: something again
phone-number = 8546521111
```

at this point the 1st loop data turns into

1st loop:

```
name: steve jobs
address: something again
phone-number = 8546521111
```

2nd loop:

```
name: steve jobs
address: something again
phone-number = 8546521111
```

So, what am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1**

Originally I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new InfoAsyncTask().execute();
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class InfoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Map<String, String>> {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            String sql = "SELECT fb_firstname, fb_lastname, fb_id FROM fbuser LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                info.put("name", resultSet.getString("fb_firstname"));
                info.put("address", resultSet.getString("fb_lastname"));
                info.put("phone_number", resultSet.getString("fb_id"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InfoAsyncTask", "Error reading school information", e);
        }

        return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, String> result) {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            TextView textViewAddress = findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
            TextView textViewPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);

            textViewName.setText(result.get("name"));
            textViewAddress.setText(result.get("address"));
            textViewPhoneNumber.setText(result.get("phone_number"));
        }
    }
}
```

But I wanted to put it into its own class file and call it from the onCreate.

Comment: Why are you bothering with threading, aside from it not being thread safe (as mentioned in below answer), the outer while loop depends on the thread completing it's work - you gain zero benefit from concurrency and will block on the caller anyway? Why not use a `CompletableFuture`, or let the caller decide threading.

Comment: The mysql connect does not work if not in the thread run. I get the error of *android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException Could not create connection to database server.* That's the only reason I am using the Threading code.

Comment: So the solution is a hack to avoid this restriction, which is there for good reason, and block the caller anyway, now resulting in other problems.. probably best that the caller runs in a different thread and this method shouldn't care about threading and mark it with `@WorkerThread`

Comment: Updated my OP with the original code I had.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you've come up with a `boolean[]` as work around substituting a simple `boolean` flag, which you can't change from the lambda expression since it should be *effectively final*. This trick would allow updating the flag, but since it might be cached by a new thread, another thread might not be able to observe that it has been updated.

To establish a so-called *happens-before* relationship, you need to use [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of a single-element `boolean` array `b`. That would guarantee that the behavior of your code is consistent.

Also, `HashMap` is not meant to be used in multithreaded environment.

## Addressing the updated question

If I've understood the issue correctly, you're trying to reimplement the code which was developed using deprecated `AsyncTask` class.

Since previously you had a code which asynchronously generating a `Map`, and returning the whole thing, you implement `Callable` interface (which contrary to `Runnable` is capable of producing the return value) to achieve the same result.

That's how such implementation might look like:

```
public class InfoTask implements Callable<Map<String, String>> {
    
    private String url;      // remove the field
    private String user;     // if you want to choose another way of providing these data
    private String password; // other than passing them to constructor
    
    // constructor
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> call() throws Exception {

        Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
            String sql = "SELECT fb_firstname, fb_lastname, fb_id FROM fbuser LIMIT 1";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                info.put("name", resultSet.getString("fb_firstname"));
                info.put("address", resultSet.getString("fb_lastname"));
                info.put("phone_number", resultSet.getString("fb_id"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InfoAsyncTask", "Error reading school information", e);
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

In order to run the [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) in a separate thread, you can use an instance of [`ExcecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which is basically a thread-management mechanism which maintains a pool of threads or a single threads and arranges execution of provided task (you can submit both `Runnable` and `Callable`).

When the task is submitted, the executor returns you an instance of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). You may think of it as if it's a container wrapping the result that is expected sometime late in the future.

To obtain an `ExcecutorService` you can use one of the static factory methods provided by [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class.

Here's a simplistic example using with a single-threaded executor:

```
InfoTask task = new InfoTask(url, user, password);
        
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Map<String, String>> future = executor.submit(task);
        
// do some stuff here
        
// NOTE: get() call is BLOCKING
Map<String, String> resultt = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // don't use parameterless get(), always provide a timeout
        
executor.shutdown(); // always invoke shutdown when executor is no longer needed
```

You can also perform a check `isDone()` to find out whether the `Future` instance contains the result:

```
if (future.isDone()) {
    Map<String, String> resultt = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Updated my OP with the original code I had.

Comment: @StealthRT So you simply want to replace the code which uses deprecated `AsyncTask`? Then you **don't** need to bother with a boolean flag and updating the Map from the concurrent thread. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a concurrency issue - when you start using threads and updating values that a different thread can see, there's no guarantee that what one thread sees is what the other one does, unless you use some form of *synchronisation*.

(Basically, to make computers run real fast, they take some liberties about the order they do things in, and where they write down their working. It's like having the current data updated on a whiteboard in an office, except to work quicker people are sometimes just writing things down on a notepad at their desk, and they'll go update the whiteboard *later*)

There are a bunch of approaches to dealing with this - you can get an overview at the [section on concurrency in the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and there are lots of tools at your disposal. I'd really recommend reading it (or something like *Java Concurrency in Practice*) because it's a really important concept to get your head around - a lot of weird and bad stuff can happen if you don't know what you're doing with threading!

But in this case, if you have a `boolean` that only *one* thread is *writing* to, and everything else is *reading* from it, you can mark that `boolean` as `volatile`. That means it updates everywhere (so everything can see the current value) as soon as it's written. That should fix your "why is it still true" problem. (Although you might need to add it as a field on the `Runnable`, and store a reference to that, since you're doing all this inside a function)

The actual data you're writing in the map is the bigger issue - you need to make sure that's synchronised. You can do that by gating all access to the map (on all threads) through a `synchronized` block, but Java also provides a few concurrency-minded collections classes like [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) that take care of that for you. But that doesn't solve all the problems related to concurrency, like race conditions - again, you have to understand the problems around this stuff, so you can be mindful about avoiding them

Comment: Updated my OP with the original code I had.

Comment: @StealthRT `AsyncTask` is a completely different thing, they run on a (single) dedicated worker thread, but the API provides thread-safe ways to pass back a return value. If your problem is just about moving the `AsyncTask` into its own class, so `onPostExecute` doesn't have access to the `Activity`'s views because it's not an inner class anymore, just create a listener parameter for your `AsyncTask` class where it can return `result`, or create a callback object that takes `result` as a parameter, that kind of thing. Then you can set it up when you start it in `onCreate`